# Is the transaction hash created before or after it is signed and sent?

Tags: transactions

Just wanted to know at what stage the transaction hashes are created in polkadot

Answer (score 2):

It is the hash of the transaction, so it is over the fully signed data.

This also means that when you receive a block with extrinsics, the same full extrinsic data can be used to re-contruct the hash (without having to decode the extrinsic first).